# Add custom static 404 and 500 error pages to a Rails app, and test they work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

How do you add custom static 404 and 500 error pages to a Rails app, and then test, with rspec, for example, that they are working?

Answer (score 2):

As a Rails Noob, I recently wanted to add custom static 404 and 500 error pages to my Rails app, and I could not find effective ways of testing. There were pieces of the puzzle in various places, but for me, not all of it fit together the way I thought should it, so I'm recording here how I made it work for my situation.  Your mileage will vary, and there may be serious flaws with this.

First, by default, Rails doesn't let errors through in development or test, because, instead it needs to give good information on the error. We want to override that, at least temporarily, so that the errors come through and get reflected in the application.

There are two configuration options you need to set. Note that you might find making these changes cause other problems for your tests. It didn't for me, but I recommend putting in both the true and false config options, with the notes, so you can comment out the setting you require for the situation at the moment. Note that the change of options requires the restart of the rails server (which happens every time you run your tests, but in development...).

In config/environments/test.rb, add, or if you already have 'config.consider_all_requests_local = ' in the file somewhere, replace it with:

```
  # Config for error handling in 'test'
  # config.consider_all_requests_local = false # For use when you need the error info.
  #
  # To have errors bubble to top, to test error handling, like 404 and 500 pages, use: 
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true # For use in test for error handling
```

Also in config/environments/test.rb, add, or if you have 'config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = ' already in the file somewhere, replace it with:

```
  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  # To have errors bubble to top, to test error handling, like 404 and 500 pages, use 'true': 
  # config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

Then, remember that if you are testing with rspec/capybara, there are often conflicts with the driver you are using. For me, the driver that worked with these tests was the webkit driver. (See https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara, and remember, as appropriate, to add to your Gemfile and 'bundle') Of course, that driver didn't work for all my other tests. So I had to set the driver only in the feature test file for these. 
Note for the test, the easiest way was a combo of before(:all) that runs once before all the tests run, and before (which is the same, as before(:each), and runs before each test):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Error pages" do
  # Get the current Capybara driver
  js_def = Capybara.javascript_driver
  before (:all) {
    # puts "Current javascript_driver is #{Capybara.javascript_driver}"
    Capybara.javascript_driver =:webkit
    # puts "Current javascript_driver is #{Capybara.javascript_driver}"
  }

  after (:all) {
    # puts "Current javascript_driver is #{Capybara.javascript_driver}"
    # Capybara.use_default_driver
    Capybara.javascript_driver =js_def
    # puts "Current javascript_driver is #{Capybara.javascript_driver}"
  }

  before {
    @user = FactoryBot.create(:user, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com")
    # @user.save!
    # @user.reload
    test_sign_in(@user)
  }

  # subject { page }

  it "renders 500 error", js: true, type: :feature do
    visit root_path
    visit raise_error_path

    expect(page.status_code).to eq(Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:internal_server_error])
    expect(page).to have_content "Apoxeia"
    expect(page).to have_content "Page Not Found"
    # expect(page).to have_link "Home"
  end

  it "renders 404 error", js: true, type: :feature do
    visit root_path

    visit 'clients/100'

    expect(page.status_code).to eq(Rack::Utils::SYMBOL_TO_STATUS_CODE[:not_found])
    expect(page).to have_content "Apoxeia"
    expect(page).to have_content "Page Not Found"
    expect(page).to have_link "Home"
  end
```

Remember that you may have to register the driver first in 'spec/spec_helper.rb' (or 'spec/rails_helper'), see the Capybara link above.

Last, you need to have a controller/action for the test.  For me, I added this to me static_pages controller:

```
  def raise_error
    raise "error"
  end
```

And this to my routes:

```
match '/raise_error', to: 'static_pages#raise_error', via: :get
```

Hope this helps.

As an aside, I have never understood the whole "dynamic errors thing". Yes, it is cool, but you can make static pages cool too!  And the idea that an 'error' should be handled with further processing is 'counter-intuitive'. If you know how to handle the error, it is not an error, it is just more application code.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting a 404 error instead of 500. Can you share the full code from github if you have uploaded it. I am stuck at it for quite some time  now :(

Comment: Am33d, I can't look at until this evening, about 12 hours from now.

Comment: Am33d, I'm sorry I have not could back to you. The thing is, I'm no longer sure this is working as it should. When I get a chance to figure out one way or another, I'll come back and respond as needed.